# Corona using object.Xscale to flip an object will cause the object to look skewed when calling object:scale(x,y)

Tags: coronasdk, scale

when trying to scale the object down on both axis the image will look skewed like, stretching more on 1 axis. I called object.Xscale=-1 to flip it. Although it works it will cause object:Scale(x,y) to have a problem with scaling. I removed the object.xScale and there seems to be no scaling issue with the display object. What can i do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you could post your code I might be able to answer you question a bit better. Until then, I can only speculate what the issue may be.

I recommend that if you do not want the xScale and yScale differing after alterations, try doing this after each change.

```
object.xScale = 2
object.yScale = math.abs(object.xScale)
```

By setting the yScale to the absolute value of xScale, you will keep it upright and the same size despite xScale possibly being negative or positive.

Hope this helps,

Joe.

Comment: hello sorry for the vague question.                                                                                 I have got a sprite image and what i did to when i move left or right is that the direction of the image will move accordingly. to do that i used object.xScale=-1 to move left and object.yScale=1 to return back to facing right.                                                                                                       As the sprite image is quite big i would need to scale it size down. But when i use object:scale(0.5,0.5) on it, the scaling will have issues.

Comment: hello sorry for the vague question.                                                                                 I have got a sprite image that moves left or right. the direction of the image will move accordingly(left or right). To do that i used object.xScale=-1 to move left and object.yScale=1 to return back to facing right.                                                                                                       As the sprite image is quite big i would need to scale it size down. But when i use object:scale(0.5,0.5) on it, the scaling will have issues. did not know edit5mins

Comment: To move and object, change it's x or y field. Like this:

obj.x = obj.x + 10 -- move right
obj.y = obj.y + 10 -- move down